# Converging Geometric Series of a a Bouncing Ball

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

A rubber ball was dropped from a height of 36m. and each time its strikes the ground it rebounds to a height of 2/3 from which it last fell. Find the total distance traveled by the ball before it comes to a rest.

Answer according to reviewer is 180m

I applied geometric series

$${ \sum_{i=0}^\infty {36\times\left( \frac{2}{3} \right)^i } = 108}$$

well actually I put 250 on the calculator instead of infinity but nonetheless it stays lke that. Is it possible problem set is wrong?

Comment: The first is $36$. But now it goes up $(2/3)(36)$ and down $(2/3)(36)$. Then it goes up $(2/3)^2(36)$ and down the same.  So we need to double your result, and subtract $36$ because the first travel was not "doubled."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have calculated the total distance the ball will *fall.* To find the total distance the ball travels (we will denote this as $B$) you must account for the rebound.

We know from your calculation the *falling* distance of the ball ($B_f$) is equal to $$B_f=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}36\bigg(\frac{2}{3}\bigg)^i=108\ \text{m}. $$

The distance the ball *rebounds* ($B_r$) is equal to the distance the ball falls minus the initial height of the ball ($I_B$), because the ball does not rebound to the initial height---only to two-thirds $I_B$.

The above can be summarized as follows:

$$B=2B_f-I_B.$$

We know $B_f=108$ and $I_B=36$. Thus, $$B=180\ \text{meters}.$$